# rails 5 private_pub and turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Добрый день!
Есть проблема с websocket в Rails, к сожалению еще не разобрался как мне реализовать функционал с помощью ActionCable, поэтому воспользовался private_pub.

Все работает, но если переходить по ссылкам и вернуться на страничку, где с помощью хелпера subscribe_to устанавливается подписка на канал, callback выполняется несколько раз (+ за каждую загрузку turbolinks).

Я думаю, что это не по вине колбека, т.к. если отправлять в канал исполняемый js, картина такая же. Мне кажется, что при каждой загрузки страницы выполняется подписка на канал отсюда такое поведение.

Как победить, не придумать...
Пишите в комментариях, какой код опубликовать, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Такое поведение вызвано тем, что каждый раз при рендеренге страницы с turbolinks, где происходит подписка на ws канал, создается новая подписка а прошлая остается работать, соответственно когда сервер пушит сообщение на странице выполняются несколько сценариев по каждой подписке. 
Нашел 3 решения задачи:

1. Использовать `ActionCable`, вместо `PrivatePub`
2. Оставить `PrivatePub`, но убрать `turbolinks`
3. Каждый раз при загрузке страницы, сначала отписываться от канала, а потом подписываться заново. В js нужно добавить следующие строчки:

   PrivatePub.unsubscribeAll();

   PrivatePub.subscribe(channel, function(data, channel) {

   });

Но в релизе функции `unsubscribeAll` нет, а в мастере репозитория есть. Похоже этот гем больше не поддерживается, последний релиз был 20 августа 2014, а последние функциональное изменение в мастере было 22 августа 2014 и больше релизов не было.
Поэтому если мы хотим оставить `PrivatePub и Turbolinks`, то в `Gemfile` нужно добавить следующею строчку:

```
gem 'private_pub', git: 'git@github.com:ryanb/private_pub.git'
```

Но я голосую за первый вариант, т.к. это работает из коробки.

Comment: В последнем варианте можно написать так: `gem 'private_pub', github: 'ryanb/private_pub` - тоже будет работать